# using bitmap, camera capture but occur nullpointerException on android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, nullpointerexception

I try camera preview capture on android.

use Bitmap.

but occur `NullpointerException`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at kr.co.mytest.test.video.CameraTextureView.getImage(CameraTextureView.java:167)
  at kr.co.mytest.test.video.CameraTextureView.onPreviewFrame(CameraTextureView.java:161)
  at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:936)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

CameraTextureView.class

```
public class CameraTextureView extends TextureView implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener, Camera.PreviewCallback {

   private Camera mCamera;
   private CaptureViewer captureView;
   . 
   . 
   . 
   @Override
   public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
      Log.d(TAG,"CHECK");

      YuvImage image = new YuvImage(data, 20, 640 ,480, null);

      Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 640, 480);
      ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      image.compressToJpeg(rect, 100, bao);

      byte[] jpeg = bao.toByteArrary();
      BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
      options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

      Bitmap convertedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpeg, 0, jpeg.length, options);
      Log.d(TAG, "convertedImage" + convertedImage);  //android.graphics.Bitmap@21ac0b78

      getImage(Bitmap.createScaleBitmap(convertedImage, 480, 360, true)); //nullPointerException
 }

 public void getImage(Bitmap bitmap) {

      ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

      captureView.displayImage(bitmap);
 }
```

CaptureView.class

```
public class CaptureView extends View {
    private Bitmap mBitmap = null;

    public void displayImage(Bitmap image) {
       mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image);
       postInvalidate();
    }
}
```

displayImage is only showing capture image.

why occur nullpointerException?

`onPreviewFrame`is Called as preview frames are displayed.

how to process occur nullPointerException?

thanks.!

Comment: smp is not assigned?

Comment: @rainash update my question. smp not use . sorry.

Comment: Maybe `getImage()` is called before captureView is assigned